# Simultaneous image capture on two webcams in matlab

Tags: matlab, stereo-3d

I am working on stereovision. I want to acquire images simultaneously from 2 Logitech webcams connected via USB ports. But I am getting the images with a long delay. How can I reduce the delay between the two captures or make the 2 cams trigger simultaneously?